# Apache Nifi ExecuteSQL Processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to fetch data from oracle database using ExecuteSQL processor.I have some queries like suppose there are 15 records in my oracle database.Here when I run the ExecuteSQL processor,it will run continuously as a streaming process and store the whole records as a single file in HDFS and repeatedly do the same.Thus many files will be there in the hdfs location which will fetch the already fetched records from oracle db and these files contains the same data.How can i make this processor to run in such a way that it must fetch all the data from oracle db once and store as a single file and when ever new records is inserted into the db,it must ingest those to hdfs location?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the QueryDatabaseTable processor:

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryDatabaseTable/index.html

You will need to tell this processor one or more columns to use to track new records, this is the Maximum Value Columns property. If your table has a one-up id column you can use that, and every time it runs it will track the last id that was seen, and start there on the next execution.

Comment: I just added an article about this subject: https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/51902/incremental-fetch-in-nifi-with-querydatabasetable.html